# My accuracy wont improve in tensorflow

Tags: recurrent-neural-networks, tensorflow

I've been trying to figure out why this model won't train (the accuracy stays at 0).

```
frame_size = 2
sequence_length = 5
input_shape = (sequence_length, frame_size)


def label_x(x: np.array):
    return np.average([np.sum(frame) for frame in x])


def build_training_set(count: int):
    xs = np.random.rand(count, *input_shape)
    return xs, (np.array([label_x(x) for x in xs]))


assert 12.4 == label_x([[1, 2], [5, 7], [12, 2], [21, 1], [5, 6]])

train_count = 10000
validate_count = int(train_count / 10)

input = Input(shape=input_shape)
hidden_1 = Dense(20, activation='relu')(input)
rnn = LSTM(20)(hidden_1)
output = Dense(1)(rnn)
model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=[output])

model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),  # Optimizer
    # Loss function to minimize
    loss="mse",
    # List of metrics to monitor
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)
print(model.summary())

x_train, y_train = build_training_set(train_count)
x_val, y_val = build_training_set(validate_count)
history = model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=64,
    epochs=200,
    validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
)
```

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: The model is only half of the problem.  You haven't given us any idea what the training dataset is or what you expect the network to be able to do.  You also do not tell us what steps you have *already* taken to figure out what's happening.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer I'm trying to train the model to sum up each time step of the sample, and the average the result of sum of each timestep (see the `label_x` function). I want to do this using an RNN layer. I've tried changing the activation functions, the loss function and the optimisers, but nothing seems to be working. I'm not sure if I'm missing something trivial or not

Answer (score 1):

The model seems to train just fine (when measured by the MSE loss), accuracy metric is only relevant when the prediction is a true / false type.

Arguably the network's structure isn't ideal for this problem, but that is beside the point.

Comment: isn't there still accuracy for the error? from the real result

Comment: it doens't work. I tested with `print([(x, y[0]) for x,y in zip( y_val, model.predict(x_val))])` after 200 epochs and the results seem random, compared to the `y_val`

Comment: After 100 epochs my code says `((model.predict(x_val) - y_val)**2).mean()` is 0.063620539. And the scatter plot looks good as well, correlation coefficient is 0.99984668648.

Comment: `[(1.249716031816869, 0.32068107), (1.1568286658676914, 0.31521273), (1.3370053550792722, 0.33378834), (1.1397021505376013, 0.23554398), (1.1691912669776516, 0.30106655), (1.0633291121420687, 0.28948098), (0.849716930324254, 0.17947169), (1.012984152099238, 0.2649205), (1.018326969664438, 0.24658701)]` look, there's no correlation. The MSE isn't relative to anything so is effectively meaningless

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/YJthW6Y.png

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/oqU11l8.png